# Verify if V is a real vector space.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Consider the differential equation $y''-y'-2y=0$. Let V be the set of all real-valued functions which are solutions of this differential equation. For any functions $f$ and $g$ in $V$ and for any real number $r$, define $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $(rf)(x)=rf(x)$. Verify if V is a real vector space. If not specify the properties which are not satisfied.

My solution:

The constant function $y=0$ satisfies the equation and so belongs to V.

If $f$, $g$ are solutions to the equation then so is $f+g$ since

$\left( f+g\right)''-\left(f+g\right)'-2\left(f+g\right)=\left(f''-f'-2f\right)+\left(g''-g'-2g\right)=0+0=0$

If $f$ is a solution to the equation then so is $rf$ for any real number $r$, since

$(rf)''-(rf)'-2(rf)=r(f''-f'-2f)=r0=0$

I am lost at this part.

Comment: *How* are you lost? Did you not prove that $f\in V\implies rf\in V$?

Comment: Your solution seems to be correct@BBS

Comment: "*I am lost at this part*"  The only final missing line, if you insist on an additional line, is one saying "[Q.E.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.#:~:text=Q.E.D.%20or%20QED%20is%20an,what%20was%20to%20be%20shown%22.)" or also sometimes written "[$\square$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.#Typographical_forms_used_symbolically)" which signifies the end of the proof, basically meaning "*[that's all folks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9434BoGkNQ).*"  Your proof is already complete.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain what your doubt is. You've shown that the $0$ function is in $V,$ and that $V$ is closed under vector addition and real scalar multiplication. This is sufficient to show that $V$ is a real vector space.

Technically, one could proceed in a slightly different way. All that is necessary is to show that $V$ is *non-empty*, closed under vector addition, and closed under scalar multiplication. As long as the first and third conditions hold, it follows that the $0$ function is an element of $V.$ In this case, it's most straightforward to simply observe that the $0$ function is in $V$ in order to show non-emptiness, unless you're able to use the fact that homogeneous linear differential equations with real eigenvalues have real solutions. If you **are** able to use that fact, then you can skip right to showing the two closure properties. Even if not, you could show that $V$ is nonempty by instead showing that $y=e^{-x}$ is an element of $V,$ for example.